# XSL Transform XMLDocument problems in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, transform, xslt, xmldocument

I have the following JavaScript to transform an XSL/XML file.

```
var xmlData = document.getElementById(controlID.value + "_XmlData");
var xsltData = document.getElementById(controlID.value + "_XsltData");

// Transform the XML using the specified XSLT file.
if ((xmlData != null) && (xsltData != null))
    reportDisplayControl.innerHTML = xmlData.transformNode(xsltData.XMLDocument);
```

I'm having an issue where the file does not get rendered in IE9.
However, if I turn on compatibility mode, it works just fine.

I've noticed the following:

1. Placing the following code: `alert(xmlData);` results in the following:

   - IE9 native: `[object HTMLUnknownElement]`
   - IE9 compatibility mode: `[object]`
2. Placing an `alert(xmlData.XMLDocument);` results in the following:

   - IE9 native: `undefined`
   - IE9 c.m.: `[object]`

Can someone help me get this working in IE 9 native mode?

Comment: Use an [XML declaration](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/04/easy-xml/) to treat the XML as a document instead of a string. var xmlData = document.createElement("xml"); xmlData.src = document.getElementById(controlID.value + "_XmlData");

Answer (score 0):

i was having this issue to... i had a look around and found out that the support for the XMLDocument property has been removed in IE9 http://help.dottoro.com/ljcdspjd.php
Also saw a blog that provided a workaround
http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2113
this might work for you...
Thanks

Update:

i solved the problem by passing the xml back asyncronously using an XMLHttprequest object in javascript and then calling the singleNode direclty.
cheers